# JSP and SERVLETS

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I created an html form coding in "index.jsp" as following ...

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="StudentController.do" method="post">
            Name:<input type="text" name="name"></br>
            Id:<input type="text" name="id"></br>
            Stream:<select name="stream">
                    <options value="UNKNOWN">select stream.....</options>
                        <options value="it">IT</options>
                            <options value="cs">CSC</options>
                                <options value="ece">ECE</options>
                                    <options value="eee">EEE</options>
                                        <options value="aerospace">AEROSPACE</options>
                   </select>>
            Sex:<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male
                    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
                            <input type="reset">
        </form>         
    </body>
</html>
```

Now i have a servlet class in which i try to access the form values ...as following

```
String i=request.getParameter(id);
String nam=request.getParameter(name);
String strea=request.getParameter(stream);
String sex=request.getParameter(sex);`
```

but it CANNOT FIND SYMBOL id , name , stream and sex ... 
Kindly guide me why this occurs ...

Thank You

Comment: Format your code properly. It's unreadable as is.

Comment: Why have you created ladder out of your code?

Comment: `id` should be enclosed in a quotes like this `"id"`, same applies for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String i = request.getParameter("id");
String nam = request.getParameter("name");
...
```

Without quotes, id and name are variables which are undefined, hence the compiler error message. You want to pass a String literal, not a variable.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
String i=request.getParameter(id);
```

to

```
String i=request.getParameter("id");
```

Else `id` would have treated as a variable and since you haven't defined this, you will get error. Same applies to others also.